# Quasar q-table WCAG

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

So am working on an application which uses Quasar (CLI) and have built a datatable with `q-table`. Now I want to make the table more accessible, and wanted to add an `aria-label` attribute to the column sorting icon, but haven't found a way.

A picture for reference: 
[image: Quasar data table sorting column] 
it is about this icon.

I've tried a few things but haven't found any solution. I'd rather not rewrite this component either since it already has quite a big codebase.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried q-table's slots?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried it, but unfortunately the slots only apply to the labels, etc. not the arror icon, so still continuing my search.

Comment: With header-cell-[name] slot you can edit the icon aswell and its properties. Perhaps I'm not fully grasping your issue

Comment: Nvm i am dumb. You are talking about the default sort icon when you make the column sortable. One way to do it would be to not make the col sortable but instead use the slot and an icon with a function with your custom sorting logic.. Maybe someone else knows more

Answer (score 2):

Since Quasar doesn't provide a way to set an aria-label for the sort icon, you can use the `document` interface to directly manipulate the DOM on mount and set the aria-labels manually.

```js
mounted() {
  const sortIcons = document.getElementsByClassName('q-table__sort-icon')
  Array.from(sortIcons).forEach(
    sortIcon => (sortIcon.ariaLabel = 'my custom label')
  )
}
```

A more "Vue-like" solution would require an update to the Quasar library which you could request as a new feature on their [github](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues).